# hover using mouseenter and mouseleave

Tags: jquery

i want a hover slider with 4 sides, wherein when i hover on a slide, it enlarges in width and the other 3 decrease i in width. i came up with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

        $('.hovermenu li').mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).animate({width: "69%"},250);
            $(this).parent().children('li').not(this).animate({width: "10%"},250);
        });

        $('.hovermenu li').mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).animate({width: "25%"},250);
            $(this).parent().children('li').not(this).animate({width: "25%"},250);
            $(this).not('li').animate({width: "10%"},250);  
        });

    });
```

but it has a problem.when i hover mouse on one slide individually(not migrating from one slide to another), the script seems to work fine, but when i move my mouse from one slide to another, the 4 slides behave very crazily and keep on changing their widths for a while, even after i keep my mouse out from the slides. 
The full fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/uprL2/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear the animation queue before starting a new one by using [`.stop(clearQueue)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/),

```
$('.hovermenu li').mouseenter(function(){
   $(this).stop().animate({width: "69%"},250);
   $(this).parent().children('li').not(this).stop(true).animate({width: "10%"},250);
});

$('.hovermenu li').mouseleave(function(){
   $(this).stop().animate({width: "25%"},250);
   $(this).parent().children('li').not(this).stop(true).animate({width: "25%"},250);   
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uprL2/6/)

Problem occurs in your case when we try to move the animation to the end state, so try to remove that second parameter from the `stop` function call. Meaning ask the function to not to jump to the end.

Comment: still some crazy movements

Comment: Probably because using `.stop(true,true)` is a better solution. This is not the default behavior of `.stop()`, so you have to specify it explicitly.

Comment: @user3450590 And by the way, if you have satisfied with anyone of the answers present here, just accept them by clicking on the tick mark. And it is not a compulsion.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.stop(true,true)` A Boolean indicating whether to complete the current animation immediately.

```
 $('.hovermenu li').mouseenter(function(){
       $(this).stop(true,true).animate({width: "69%"},250);
       $(this).parent().children('li').not(this).stop(true,true).animate({width: "10%"},250);
    });

     $('.hovermenu li').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).stop(true,true).animate({width: "25%"},250);
        $(this).parent().children('li').not(this).stop(true,true).animate({width: "25%"},250);   
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uprL2/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this .hope it helps

```
  $('.hovermenu li').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({width: "69%"},250);
  $(this).parent().children('li').not(this).stop(true,true).animate({width: "10%"},250);
 });

$('.hovermenu li').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({width: "25%"},250);
  $(this).parent().children('li').not(this).stop(true,true).animate({width: "25%"},250);   
});
```